# Is there a difference between writing $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$, $\frac{df}{dx}$, and $\frac{df}{dx}(x)$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, notation

Say $f(x)=x^2$. Sometimes I have seen written

$$
\frac{df(x)}{dx}=2x
$$

Other times I have seen

$$
\frac{df}{dx}=2x
$$

Is there any difference between these two notations? The second one in particular looks odd to me as $f$ refers to a function, rather than the output of a function. To make matters worse, sometimes I see

$$
\frac{df}{dx}(x)=2x
$$

Which seems to imply that $df/dx$ is a function, and $\frac{df}{dx}(x)$ refers to the function evaluated at the point $x$.

Comment: It is generally understood that the (slightly) different notations all refer to the same thing.

Comment: All of those refer to the same thing, friend !

Comment: These are identical, generally. But imagine this task: "evaluate first derivative at $x=5$." Then the second notation isn't sufficiently rich to write this as nowhere on the left hand side $x$ appears as the argument. For the others, you just replace $x$ by 5.

Comment: I disagree with the consensus here. To me, the first and third notation both say "the derivative of $f$ evaluated at $x$", while the second says "the derivative of $f$". The same difference as the one between $f$ and $f(x)$. The former is a function, the latter is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same, but I think there's a little bit more to be said. This is not a technical answer, but is how I like to think about it:

${\frac{df}{dx}(x)}$ means "take the derivative of $f$, and evaluate this new function at the point $x$".

${\frac{df(x)}{dx}}$ means "take $f$ at the point $x$ and find the derivative there"

${\frac{df}{dx}}$ is pretty much the same as the first one, but we don't have an evaluation point specified. By convention, we assume we are evaluating at the point $x$. But this doesn't have to be the case. For example, you could do ${\frac{df}{dx}(x^2)}$, meaning "take the derivative of the function $f$ and evaluate it at the point ${x^2}$.

Anyways - overall you can see how they are all essentially equivalent.